# How can I show up my email in white color on foot widget? It is floating

Tags: email, colors, fonts, widget

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0yEL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3rvE.png)

My website is https://1mortgagebroker.ca

On my Wordpress Foot Widget, I put the code as follows:

BBA MBA MA CPA FCCA FCMA

Brokerage FSRA Lic. #12176

416-618-9312

Email us (click here)

With You in Every Step: Nearly 30 Years of Home Guidance!!

I don't know what I am missing. In the body, I used Elementor that is easier to edit, but I can't use Elementor to edit the foot widget, thanks for your help.

Wanted to show the email address permanently in white color, with a link to open an email. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your site and I found out you made the changes to your footer and made the email text white but I found out its mailto is not working just because you put the code in the visual field of the text editor.

To fix this put your mailto code in the text field which is shown below in the image

The code to put :

```
<p><a href="mailto:maurice@sherwoodmortgagegroup.com">maurice@sherwoodmortgagegroup.com</a></p>
```

You can take help from the image below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLuX0.png)